# import with maven repository

Tags: android, maven, gradle, retrofit

i´m trying to import `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT'`
as is shown in this tutorial https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses/ currently using retrofit 2.0.0-beta2, but if just add the compile line it gets me an error, what do i have to do to get it working?
 this is my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.diegolimon.wedrivetogether"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.3'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

the logging-interceptor:2.6.0-snapshot is supposed to be included in the retrofit 2.0.0-beta2.

Comment: have u tried to add the `@aar` ?at the end of that line?

Comment: Whats the error you're getting?

Comment: Error: Failed to resolve: com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT @RaGe

Comment: you mean like .. compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT@arr'  ? @eduyayo

Comment: you do not have a `repositories` section in your gradle script?

Comment: i was missing the `repositories {
        jcenter()

        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        }
}` thanks @RaGe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was missing this in the build.gradle of the project.

```
repositories {
        jcenter()

        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Really using SNAPSHOT repositories?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes.. its the best way to debug retrofit requests

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a `repositories` section in your build.gradle

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
  mavenLocal()
}
```

The repositories section tells gradle where to look for the dependencies. The search happens in the order in which the repositories are listed.